# Determining if Swift dictionary doesn't contains a key and set default value

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a quiz app, in app user can select an answer or no. If user skip question without answer I want to add a dictionary 0 values for that question. If select A I add 1 for B add 2 etc until E. In my case for question 1, key:1 -> represent question 1 and  value:1 -> represent A answer. If user select a choice I added dictionary. If user skip without any answer, I didn't add answer.

```
 userAnswerDict = [(key: 1, value: 4), (key: 2, value: 5), (key: 4, value: 4), (key: 6, value: 4), (key: 7, value: 5), (key: 9, value: 2)
```

My problems begins here. I want to add for key = 3, key = 5, key = 8 default value = 0. My question total is 20. How can I do it?

Comment: The *dictionary* is actually an array of tuples. You are discouraged from using tuples for persistent data.

Comment: I have the impression that a dictionary is the wrong datastructure for that task. Why not use something like `var userAnswers = [Answer]` with `Answer` being either a class or a struct or even simply a enum with case "NoAnswer" and "GivenAnswer(Int)" with an associated value.

Comment: @vadian What is your suggestion ?

Comment: The same as luk2302's

Comment: @luk2302, how can I determine question number and giving answer ? Can you explain your suggest please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems easier for me if you just use an array of integers initialized with all 0, like:

```
var answers = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 20)
```

Then, when the user answer the "index" question you just do:

```
answers[index] = userAnswer //A number based on the choices option
```

Or you can access the answer for a question with:

```
userSaidForIndexQuestion = answers[index] //Will be 0 if you never add an answer
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can create structure for answer and manage it easily like as following code:

```
struct Answer {
    var questionId: Int
    var answerValue: Int?
}

let answer1 = Answer(questionId: 1, answerValue: 5)
let answer2 = Answer(questionId: 2, answerValue: nil)

let arrAnswers = [answer1, answer2]
```

If you want to replace nil value with 0 then you can use following function:

```
let arrNewAnswers = arrAnswers.flatMap { (answer) -> Answer in
    if answer.answerValue == nil {
        return Answer(questionId: answer.questionId, answerValue: 0)
    }
    return answer
}
```

**Output:**

First array contains nil value

> print(arrAnswers)
>
> [Answer(questionId: 1, answerValue: Optional(5)), Answer(questionId: 2, answerValue: nil)]

Second array updated 0 to nil.

> print(arrNewAnswers)
>
> [Answer(questionId: 1, answerValue: Optional(5)), Answer(questionId: 2, answerValue: Optional(0))]

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: isAnswered looks redundant to me

Comment: Yes, we can remove it, because there are null value allowed for answer.